# Eavaluating the roots of quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $b>a , c>0$ 
Determine the intervals that the roots of the equation
$(x-a)(x-b) -c =0$ belong to 
My work is to get the values of the roots in terms of a , b and c using the general form but i couldn't determine those intervals

Comment: in the general formula put instead of $b$ the value $a$ to get lower bound and then instead of $a$ the value $b$ to get upper bound and all the values  in between represent the interval that the solutions in.

Comment: The roots belong to  *what*?

Answer (score 0):

First solve for $x$ the quadratic equation $(x-a)(x-b)-c=0$ by the general form we get that $x_1 =\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-2 a b+b^2+4 c}+a+b\right)$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{a^2-2 a b+b^2+4 c}+a+b\right)$

substituting instead of $b$ the value $a$ we get that $x_1 >\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a+2 \sqrt{c}\right) $ and $x_2 > \frac{1}{2} \left(2 a-2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ because $b>a$.

substituting instead of $a$ the value $b$ we get that $x_1< \frac{1}{2} \left(2 b+2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $x_2 <\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b-2 \sqrt{c}\right) $

the smallest value of $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a+2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a-2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b+2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b-2 \sqrt{c}\right) $

is $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a-2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ since $a<b$ and $c>0$.

the biggest value of $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a+2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a-2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b+2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b-2 \sqrt{c}\right) $

is $\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b+2 \sqrt{c}\right)$ since $b>a$ and $c>0$.

thus the roots are in the interval $[\frac{1}{2} \left(2 a-2 \sqrt{c}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(2 b+2 \sqrt{c}\right)]$

Comment: The intervals are required numericaly not in terms of a , b and c

Answer (score 0):

The given equation is $x^2-(a+b)x+ab-c=0$. But $$\Delta=(a+b)^2-4(ab-c)=(a-b)^2+4c>0.$$ So the equation has two distinct real roots. The two roots are $\frac{(a+b)+\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4c}}{2}$ and $\frac{(a+b)-\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4c}}{2}$. Hence the roots are in the interval $[\frac{(a+b)-\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4c}}{2},\frac{(a+b)+\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4c}}{2}]$.

Comment: The intervals are required numericaly not in terms of a , b and c